# function to bringout only the decimal in sas

Tags: function, sas

There are functions to bring out the integer value and also to round up the value. 
But I want the first decimal value in a new variable. How can I do that. 
for ex: if the valur is 12.62 I want 0.6 in the new variable. and 12 in another variable.

```
newvar1 =INT(12.62)   /* this gives 12 as output*/
newvar2 =??(12.62)    /* for the output to be 0.6*/
```

Answer (score 3):

You wanted a function - you can roll your own in 9.3+ .

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.math;
  function firstdec(in);
    out = floor(in*10 - floor(in)*10)/10;
    return(out);
  endsub;
quit;

options cmplib=work.funcs;

data _null_;
  x=12.62;
  newvar = firstdec(x);
  put newvar=;
run;
```

Comment: Of course any of the above solutions could also be used inside the `firstdec` function - I used my preferred method.

Comment: One caveat I realised afterwards is that `floor` only works in this case with positive numbers.  If there are negative numbers then `int` is a better option

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of `floor` and `mod` to truncate the decimal rather than round.  `mod` returns the remainder when the first number is divided by the second.

```
data first_decimal;
input x;
y = int(x);
z = floor(mod(x, int(x))/0.1) * 0.1;
datalines;
12.62
;
run;
```

Comment: Even simpler would be `z = int((x-int(x))*10)/10;`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the floor function.

```
yourvar = 12.62;
newvar2 = round(yourvar - floor(yourvar), .1);
```

Comment: Hi, but this rounds off the 0.62 to 0.6 and 0.68 to 0.7

I am looking to bring out the first decimal value.

Comment: You can't use `round` where the 2nd decimal is between 5 and 9. e.g. 12.65 will show as 0.7

Comment: You are correct keith., 

I actually used character function and then converted it to numeric after scan function...like this:

   `code`  f=put(a,5.3);
    `code` r=substr(scan(f,2,'.'),1,1);
`code`    u=(input(r,best.))/10;


This might not be the best way to do it.. so I am windering if we have any numeric function,

Answer (score 1):

Keith's answer is also correct he is doing mathematical operations, while I am performing char functions

1. Converting the numeric to character.
2. Scanning for the decimal "." and obtaining the next character
3. Appending 0. to the obtained number in 2

---

```
data _NULL_;
input x;
y = int(x);
k= cat("0.",substr(scan(put(x,best32.),2,"."),1,1));
datalines;
12.6212
;
run;
```

Comment: Hi NEO, i did the same thing :)

I mean I followed the same procedure

Answer (score 0):

```
newvar1 =INT(12.62) ; 
newvar2 =abs(12.62) - INT(12.62) ;  /* --> THIS GIVES .62 AS OUTPUT.*/
```

If you want .6 as output then it is

```
NEWVAR2 = ROUND((ABS(12.62) - int(12.62)),.1);
```